# react-select to stretch to fit value

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-select

I have a very simple setup - a `display: flex` header with a logo on the left and a `react-select` on the right.

[image]

But, as you can see, `react-select` doesn't stretch to fit the value. I've tried a lot of options, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have a solution?

[Here's the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-brattain-k9fmj?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: the select doens't seem to select the actual thing i select. but changing `.css-1uccc91-singleValue` to `position: relative` makes the text visible atleased (doesnt select before css change aswell. its not based on this change that its not working for me)

Comment: try this: .css-g1d714-ValueContainer { min-width:50px;}

Comment: Thanks, but I should probably point out that I would like a flexible solution, so no absolute values.

Comment: make sure the singleValue's are not on `position absolute` but something like relative or whatever, so you can tell the parent to get a width according to the children's biggest width (`width: fit-content`)

Answer (score 0):

Just add styles and className property to Select component

```
.yourSelect {
  min-width: 200px;
}


<Select options={options} className='yourSelect' />
```